What's "fall in with" mean in "Unknowingly, we have fallen in with the symbolism of rebirth"?
This context comes from the book "Man And His Symbols" by Carl G. Jung.
"At Christmas we may express our inner feeling for the mythological birth of a semi-divine child, even though we may not believe in the doctrine of the virgin birth of Christ or have any kind of conscious religious faith. Unknowingly, we have fallen in with the symbolism of rebirth."

fall in with:
Agree with, be in harmony with, as in We happily fell in with his plans. [First half of 1600s](The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer.)

fall in with:
Associate with, become acquainted with (especially by chance), as in On the cruise we fell in with a couple from Boston. [Late 1500s](The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer.)


3.fall in(to):
To begin to participate in something with others.
How did you end up falling into a lecture with Grandpa about the Farmers' Almanac?
Please don't fall into an argument with Uncle Ned on Christmas, OK?
Mrs. Smith, how did you get the cool kids to fall into Math Club? (Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2024 Farlex,)
Did we uknowingly become knowledgeable about the symbolism, start to agree with it or to begin to participate in a festival that is symbolic?


Become in harmony with. See also Merriam-Webster #2


"At Christams"  should probably be "As Christians".

@TimR - Or "At Christmas", surely?

@TimR I was touch-typing the text while reading it on my kindle, heh.

@KateBunting Yes, probably even more likely.

fall in to and fall in with have different meanings.

@TimR I know that. I provided options to choose from. I thought that it might be possible that the "fall in(to)" might be possible as when the word is in parenthesis it might be used or omitted.

You mention "become knowledgeable about." That meaning isn't present here; I suspect you're getting it from "become acquainted with." We use that phrase to speak of knowledge sometimes, "I'm acquainted with polynomials," but the dictionary means it more along the original lines of "to meet someone or something."

In 'Western' countries, people without a conscious religious faith often do participate in Christmas carol singing, for example, but usually from a fondness for tradition - they don't 'begin' to do it.
I think Jung (or his translator) is referring to people instinctively sharing in a mood of optimism - of Christmas being 'special' - even if they don't believe in the doctrine of the Incarnation. So it is the 'be in harmony with' definition.

Thank you for this Kate :)

To "fall in with (a group of people)" means to be frequently in their company, so that one is being influenced by them and having one's opinions and even one's thinking and behavior changed as a result of that influence.  To "be in agreement or harmony with" is another way of expressing part of that meaning, though it doesn't capture the notion of "influence" that the idiom often has. One who "falls in" with someone or something is receptive to them or to it.

She has fallen in with a bad crowd and comes in at all hours of the night.
She has fallen in with a group of buskers who play near the train station. They're really quite good. They are all classically trained.

When a military officer issues the command "Fall in!" the soldiers line up in an orderly manner. "Harmony" and "agreement" are probably not the most apt way to describe that conformity and order.
Here in the context that Jung is speaking of, "we" are not socializing or consorting with a small group of people knowingly, but are being influenced unknowingly, without our being aware of it, by the prevailing culture around "us", by a society in which symbols of rebirth are prevalent.  We are receptive to that symbolism without being consciously aware of that.
